# How can I get a SelectListItem other than the one with value=0 to be selected by default?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `<select>` for weekdays in a ViewComponent Default.cshtml, each day with the associated values of 0-6 (Sunday to Saturday). However, I want Monday to be listed as the first day, so in my ViewModel, I have this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> SelectableWeekdays => new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Monday", Value = "1", Selected = true },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Tuesday", Value = "2", Selected = false },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Wednesday", Value = "3", Selected = false },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Thursday", Value = "4", Selected = false },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Friday", Value = "5", Selected = false },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Saturday", Value = "6", Selected = false },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Sunday", Value = "0", Selected = false }
};
```

In my view, I'm rendering the dropdown like this:

```
<select asp-for="Weekday" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.SelectableWeekdays">
</select>
```

I have also tried adding a selected, disabled option manually:

```
<select asp-for="Weekday" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.SelectableWeekdays">
    <option selected disabled>Please choose</option>
</select>
```

No matter what I have been trying, the selected option is always "Sunday" with the attribute `selected="selected"` being set for that day.

I have also tried adding

```
new SelectListItem { Text = "Please choose", Value = "99", Selected = true, Disabled = true },
```

in the ViewModel, and omitting the manual option in my view, but that didn't work either. The disabled "Please choose"-option was there at the top of the list, but Sunday was still the selected option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is the value of the underlying model's property `Weekday`.

If you set the value of this property to the option you want selected by default (`1` in this case), the control will be rendered accordingly.

Comment: @Stian Ha!... I am glad I was able to help. :-)